# Can I reset array values using a list?

Tags: c, arduino

I am programming for the Arduino. I want to use an array, but I want to change the contents of the array, while the code is running with the same code I used to initialize the array:

I can do this:

```
boolean framebuffer[6][5] = {
    {0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1}
  };
```

But I can't do this:

```
  framebuffer = {
    {0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1}
  };
```

Is there any possibility to set the array content like this? I don't want assign each array element individually, like this:

```
  framebuffer[0][0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly do it like that, but you can have all your arrays predefined, then `memcpy` them to `framebuffer`:

```
// Put all your preconstructed items in some array.....
// You'd typically make this a global.

boolean glyphs[2][6][5] = {
    {
        {0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1}
    },
    {
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,1,1},
        {1,0,1,0,1},
        {1,1,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1}
    }
};

// Then whereever you want to change the framebuffer in your code:
// copy the second into a framebuffer:
memcpy(framebuffer, glyphs[1], sizeof(boolean)*6*5);
```